# Will I ever run into problems if I don't clean before I build?

Tags: xcode, git, xcodebuild, pre-commit-hook

I've written a git pre-commit hook that aborts the commit if my xcode project fails to compile.

It does this by running xcodebuild with the appropriate settings for my project.  If the xcodebuild returns a non-zero status then you can't commit your changes.

Here is the xcodebuild command I'm running:

```
xcodebuild -project MYPROJ/MYPROJ.xcodeproj -target MYPROJ -configuration Debug clean build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='iPhone Developer' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

What I want to know is what issues will I run into if I remove the "clean" from the build command?  I have a vague understanding of what "clean" does: remove previously compiled objects which will cause the following build command to build the entire project from scratch.

However, a full build takes a long time on our project whereas if we don't do a clean and haven't modified a lot, it can only take a few seconds.  I'd like to keep our pre-commit-hooks fast and lightweight but I'm worried the build will get in some weird state and prevent a developer from being able to commit even though their code is fine.

Will I run into issues if I don't clean before every build for my pre-commit hook? Will it possibly incorrectly report a build error in some cases or get out of whack if I don't clean?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have certainty that your commit compiles, you should clean before building. Sometimes libraries and resources can get messed up, that's why the clean command exists. You want to make sure that someone who would check out that revision could compile the project with no issues. You can't guarantee that if you might have some leftovers from previous builds, such as old resources.

Imagine using an image for your GUI. You compile your app and it works. Then you restructure your resources a bit and somehow end up removing the image from the project. If you run the app again, it can still load the old image if you don't clean the project. So it will work for you, but not for someone with a clean build.

Comment: +1 Also when your project contains 100's of classes and files, then even an added method in any file is not reflected in other classes.